# Batch convertion of .tab files to a single .gml using ogr2ogr

Tags: convert, ogr2ogr, gml, tab

My task is to convert .tab files from a directory (`C:\Users\Vadim\Downloads\vec\MapInfo\snp`) to a single GML file (snp.gml).
I use OSGeo4w Shell.
So I wrote a following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GML" C:\Users\Vadim\Downloads\vec\snp.gml -dsco FORMAT=TAB C:\Users\Vadim\Downloads\vec\MapInfo\snp
```

But it printed an error:

```
FAILURE: Unable to open datasource 'C:\Users\Vadim\Downloads\vec\MapInfo\snp' with the following drivers...
```

Could you please help me to get this command work.

Comment: At least `-dsco FORMAT=TAB` will do nothing because you want to write out GML and that format does not have such dataset creation option. Does `ogrinfo C:\Users\Vadim\Downloads\vec\MapInfo\snp` list your tab files as layers?

Comment: no, the same error appears

Comment: And you certainly have tab files there `dir C:\Users\Vadim\Downloads\vec\MapInfo\snp\*.tab` ?

Comment: exactly, it listed all the tabs

Comment: And is ogrinfo OK if you run it for one of the tab files `ogrinfo C:\Users\Vadim\Downloads\vec\MapInfo\snp\my_file.tab`? Do you have any other files than .tab and accompanied files (dat, id, map) in that directory?

Comment: You are right: I had 1 additional tab file for raster layer. After deleting it and implementing the command again I got the gml.file! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

GDAL tries to detect MapInfo vector files from a directory https://www.gdal.org/drv_mitab.html. However, the autodetection may fail if there are other files in the same directory. For example, if directory contains shapefiles only those are reported as layers because the shapefile driver makes the test first.

In your case you found yourself that you had one raster tab file in your data directory. Obviously that fooled ogrinfo and ogr2ogr to believe that there are no vectors at all in the directory.

The solution was to delete the extra tab file from the directory. Best practice is probably to keep only the MapInfo vector files (.TAB, .MAP, .DAT, .ID) in a directory that will be used as a GDAL dataset with multiple layers.